# How can I remove a create review form after submitting using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm making an app where users can write reviews on venues and currently have an add review form on the venues show page. When a user adds a review it updates the page with AJAX and displays the review. When the page is reloaded it recognises that the current user has written a review and doesn't show the add new review form.

How can I add that into the AJAX function so that is automatically removes the add new review form on submitting a review?

**venue show.html.erb**

```
  <div id="reviews">
    <%= render :partial => 'reviews/review', :collection => @venue.reviews %>
  </div>

  <% unless reviewed? %>
    <%= form_for [@venue, @review], :class => 'rating_ballot' do |f| %>
      <%= f.label("value_1", content_tag(:span, '1'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"1"}) %>
      <%= radio_button_tag("review[rating]", 1, :class => 'rating_button') %>

      <%= f.label("value_2", content_tag(:span, '2'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"2"}) %>
      <%= radio_button_tag("review[rating]", 2, :class => 'rating_button') %>

      <%= f.label("value_3", content_tag(:span, '3'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"3"}) %>
      <%= radio_button_tag("review[rating]", 3, :class => 'rating_button') %>

      <%= f.label("value_4", content_tag(:span, '4'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"4"}) %>
      <%= radio_button_tag("review[rating]", 4, :class => 'rating_button') %>

      <%= f.label("value_5", content_tag(:span, '5'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"5"}) %>
      <%= radio_button_tag("review[rating]", 5, :class => 'rating_button') %> <br>

      <p>title: <br>
      <%= f.text_field :title %></p><br>

      <%= submit_tag %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

**review _review.html.erb**

```
<div class="review">

  <div class="reviewer_details">
    <div class="reviewer_details_photo"></div>
    <%= review.user.username %>
  </div>

  <div class="review_content">
    <h2 class="review_partial_title"><%= link_to review.title, [@venue, review] %></h><br>
    <p><%= review.rating %></p>
  </div>

  <div class="clearall"></div>
</div>
```

**review create.js.erb**

```
$("#new_review").before('<div id="flash_notice"><%= escape_javascript(flash.delete(:notice)) %></div>');
$("#reviews_count").html("<%= pluralize(@review.venue.reviews.count, 'Review') %>");
$("#reviews").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @review)) %>");
$("#new_review")[0].reset();
```

Thanks for any help its much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view, wrap the form in a div with an id, say "review_form".

```
    <div id="reviews">
    <%= render :partial => 'reviews/review', :collection => @venue.reviews %>
    </div>
    <% unless reviewed? %>
    <div id="review_form">
    <%= form_for [@venue, @review], :class => 'rating_ballot' do |f| %>
      <%= f.label("value_1", content_tag(:span, '1'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"1"}) %>
      <%= radio_button_tag("review[rating]", 1, :class => 'rating_button') %>

      <%= f.label("value_2", content_tag(:span, '2'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"2"}) %>
      <%= radio_button_tag("review[rating]", 2, :class => 'rating_button') %>

      <%= f.label("value_3", content_tag(:span, '3'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"3"}) %>
      <%= radio_button_tag("review[rating]", 3, :class => 'rating_button') %>

      <%= f.label("value_4", content_tag(:span, '4'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"4"}) %>
      <%= radio_button_tag("review[rating]", 4, :class => 'rating_button') %>

      <%= f.label("value_5", content_tag(:span, '5'), {:class=>"rating", :id=>"5"}) %>
      <%= radio_button_tag("review[rating]", 5, :class => 'rating_button') %> <br>

      <p>title: <br>
      <%= f.text_field :title %></p><br>

      <%= submit_tag %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Then, in create.js.erb, add some jquery to clear its contents, hide, or remove it all together.

`$("#review_form").hide();`

Comment: Thanks very much! great answer, feel daft I couldn't figure that out thanks again